# Difference (except) between two dimensional array of type <class> and List of type <class>

Tags: c#

Lets have a class called "ClassA" and lets have the following code:

```
...
ClassA[,] all = new ClassA[8,8];
...
//Array "all" is filled with objects
...
List<ClassA> some = new List<ClassA>();
...
//List "some" is filled with some objects taken from all
...
List<ClassA> others = new List<ClassA>();
```

Now I'd like to get the difference between "all" and "some", for example something like this:
other = all - some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can use `Except`:

```
var others = all.Except(some);
```

In your specific case with the two dimensional array, you first have to bring `all` into the right "form" using `Cast`:

```
var others = all.Cast<ClassA>().Except(some);
```